System crashes desperately need grub fixes
Basic information about the system on which the problem occurs:


the operating system is RHEL9.2, running on VMware17 virtual machine
the total size of the hard disk 40g, my hard disk using MBR partition format, there were three primary partitions, respectively nvme0n1p1 ~ p3, the size of 500m, 20g, 2g respectively
/boot mounted on nvme0n1p1, / mounted on nvme0n1p2, /swap mounted on nvme0n1p3

Background of the problem: My purpose is to expand the capacity of /boot, because I upgraded the kernel before, which caused the partition nvme0n1p1 under /boot to be almost full, and there is only 9m left.
How the problem occurs:
All the following formatting operations select the filesystem xfs.
The method I used was to create an extended partition and create a logical partition of size 1.5g on it and perform a format, then I tarballed and compressed everything under /boot and put it into /boot_old, then I reformatted the /nvme0n1p1 partition with the mkfs utility (deleting the original data) and uninstalled the /boot with the umount command. /boot, then I mounted the 1.5g logical partition to /boot, then I deleted the nvme0n1p1 partition by using fdisk, then I extracted the zip from /boot_old to /boot which I just mounted to the logical partition, then I restarted the system, and found that the system can not be booted normally, the error diagram is as below, what should I do now?
The following image shows what happens when I enter the grub command line after booting the system:

